# Pick Image Files From Gallery In Android 11 and Above Or Below in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions

I have a problem, I want to get images on devices with android versions lower and higher than 10, but it only takes those from lower than 10, how could I solve this problem?

I tried this...

XML

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
```

My Class

```
layoutMiscellaneous.findViewById(R.id.laoutAddImage).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        CreateNoteActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION
                );
            } else {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

private void selectImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())  != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECTED_IMAGE);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION && grantResults.length > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                selectImage();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permissao_recusada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

So What can i do?

Comment: Picking a photo is [exactly the example directly from the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). You don't need any of that permission code or anything version specific. Why do you think any of that is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The `maxSdkVersion` attribute which you have given in the manifest file will not provide the permission level above 29. So, for that you need to remove it and make a small change in that:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: But...as you could have read in a comment on the post that permission is not needed. And has nothing to do with the problem. So why talk about it?

Comment: If so then need to create a new storage access framework. `ActivityResultContracts` Api will request the storage permission and read images.